# d3js select element after on click event

Tags: typescript, select, d3.js

I am not able to select the element after an on click event with d3.

my code :

```
this.node = this.svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(data.nodes)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 4)
      .attr("fill", (d) => { return this.color(d.kind); })
      .on('click', function (d, event) {
        console.log(d3.event.currentTarget)
        console.log(d['id'])
        console.log(event)
        console.log(d3.select(d3.event.currentTarget).select("circle").empty())
        d3.select(this).select("circle")
          .transition()
          .attr("r", 16)
```

As you see, I would like to change the r attribute of the selected element but it doesn't work.

Here are the console :

```
<circle r=​"4" fill=​"#1f77b4" style=​"-webkit-tap-highlight-color:​ rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)​;​" cx=​"641.4375020534999" cy=​"652.293126144675">​…​</circle>​
ESCAPP
 368
 true
```

So what I don't understand is that the event does point to an element but d3 doesn't select it.

Note : I am using typescript and Angular 2

Comment: Does d3.select(this).attr("r", 16) work? I don't think the .select("circle") is necessary, and haven't used transitions yet, but checking you can change the "r" would seem like a logical first step.

Comment: `d3.select(this)`  should be sufficient

Comment: You are right, removing select('circle') was the solution, Thanks !